# VBA regex everything after words

Tags: regex, excel, csv, regex-lookarounds, vba

I have the sentence "lorem ipsum dolor marker words blah blah blah"

I need only the words *after* (but not including) 'marker words'. 'Marker words' are the only words in the sentence that remain the same.

I managed to find `(?<=\bmarker words\s)(\w+)` which not only doesn't work in vba, but it also returns only one word after the marker words ex: `blah` but I'm not sure how to extend this to the rest of the string (if I were to work on it outside of Excel). My research says that vba doesn't even support lookbehinds at all so I am stuck.

Comment: You mean you need [`\bmarker words\s+(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/yE0gF8/2)? `blah blah blah` as output? (reformatted)

Comment: Thanks, that works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA VBScript regex does not support lookbehind construct. You can only rely on *capturing*:

```
\bmarker words\s+(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE0gF8/2)

The result is in the [**`SubMatches` collection**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y27d2s18(v=vs.84).aspx).

The `\bmarker words\s+` subpattern matches the whole words `marker words` followed with 1 or more whitespace(s) and `(.*)` subpattern matches zero or more characters other than a newline and places it into a capture group, a memory buffer, where the value can be further retrieved from with language specific  methods.

VBA code:

```
Sub CaptureSubstring()
  Dim str As String
  Dim objMatches As Object
  str = "lorem ipsum dolor marker words blah blah blah"
  Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")     ' Declare the RegExp object
  objRegExp.Pattern = "\bmarker words\s+(.*)"         ' Set pattern
  Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(str)             ' Execute the regex match
  If objMatches.Count <> 0 Then                       ' Check the result
    Debug.Print objMatches.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0) ' Print Match 1, Submatch 1
    ' > blah blah blah
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the generous explanation as well. <3

Answer (score 0):

Try following regex:

```
"(?:marker words)(.*?)$"
```

Your string should be in first group.